# Kendo UI Web - DropDownList: select event doesn't return selected value properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am binding a `DropDownList` widget to `select` event like so:

```
var items = [
    { text: 'Item 3', value: '3' },
    { text: 'Item 4', value: '4' }
];

var dropDownListEl = $('#dropdownlist');
dropDownListEl.kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: 'text',
    dataValueField: 'value',
    index: 0
});

var kDropDownList = dropDownListEl.data('kendoDropDownList'),
    ds = kDropDownList.dataSource;

items.forEach(function (item) {
    ds.add(item);
});

kDropDownList.bind('select', function (e) {
    console.log('this.value(): ' + this.value());
});
```

But, it doesn't return the correct value when I do the selection.

I have been trying almost every possibility there is, none is working. http://jsfiddle.net/glenn/gxJ3S/

It's driving me insane!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Binding **Select Event** of **Kendo DropDownList** as follow to get correct selected item

```
   kDropDownList.bind('select', function (e) {
       var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
        console.log('this.value(): ' + dataItem.value);

   });
```

[Here is the working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23r9s/1/)

Comment: Do note now you should use `this.dataItem(e.item)` instead. See http://www.telerik.com/forums/drop-down-list-dataitem-returns-incorrect-item#bjLQ8DTUL0WGY6IcWy5zUA

Answer (score 3):

use [change](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-change) event instead, it's more straightforward

```
..
  change: function(e) {
    var value = this.value();
    // Use the value of the widget
  }
..
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you use angular, you can get the selected item with:
 `e.sender.dataItem(e.item.index())`

Answer (score 1):

```
var _item = e.sender.dataItem(e.sender.selectedIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Kendo changed their API:

> Important: Since version Q1 2015 (2015.1.318), the option label has
>   been moved outside the item list DOM collection. As a result,
>   jQuery.index() can no longer be used to reliably detect if the option
>   label is the selected dropdown item.

Ref. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-select

Ultimately, this is the only thing that worked for me:

```
var item = e.sender.dataItem(e.item)
```