# Kendo, kendoDropDownList, _selectedValue, always the first option

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, selectedvalue, selectedindex

This is probably easy but I'm stuck.

I have a function that works with a kendoDropDownList and I cannot retrieve the value of the selectedIndex. Ignoring what the function actually does, can someone explain this?

```
function setDocTypeAssociates(event){

    var dropdownlist = $("#type_doma_ky").data("kendoDropDownList");
    console.log(dropdownlist); 
    console.log(dropdownlist._selectedValue); 
    console.log(dropdownlist.selectedIndex); 
    ...
```

The result of those three console.log()s you can see in the attached screendump.

Why are the values correct (65 and 4) in the object, yet incorrect (67 and 0) when I dump them individually?

[image: Screendump]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32476521/1849455

Comment: Reason could be dependent code , could you please reproduce the same in a jsfiddle ? and fyi never use _variable for development as they are considered are private members.

Comment: If we suspect dependent code, I couldn't possibly set this up in jsFiddle. It would be hard enough to produce an isolated version anyway what with all the frameworks and OO type code we are using. 

I guess my specific question was more theoretical. How can two consecutive dumps produce different results for the same variable? Am I, for example, accessing the values in the second and third dumps in the wrong way? Is there maybe a more appropriate syntax I should use?

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to say why you get these results, I personally tried to reproduce them and was unable.

Any way the best way to get your data would be:

```
      var dropdownlist = $("#list").data("kendoDropDownList");
      console.log(dropdownlist); 
      console.log(dropdownlist.text()); 
      console.log(dropdownlist.value());    
      console.log(dropdownlist.selectedIndex);
```

with text() and value() functions.

In general Telerik does not recommend using fields that start with underscore because they are setup for internal use and might change. For example in the latest version of Kendo UI _selectedValue returns undefined.

I have created working example for your reference.

http://dojo.telerik.com/eNUkU

Comment: Hi Stefan

Same problem. I can't put a screen dump in this dialogue window, but here is what I get:

console.log(dropdownlist); 
 text = Press Card
 value = 65
 selectedIndex = 4
 (ie. the fifth item in the selectBox)

Individually accessed:
 console.log(dropdownlist.text()); = Articles or contributions
 console.log(dropdownlist.value()); = 67 
 console.log(dropdownlist.selectedIndex); = 0
 (ie. the first item in the selectBox)

How can that be???? :-(

Comment: Hi Stefan. Could you take a look at the dojo link? When I run it I get a "http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.2.805/js/angular.min.js.map 404 (Not Found)" in the console.

Comment: hi Michael, I really don't know why you get this result. I need to see your code to try to get idea. It shouldn't be. which dojo link are you referring to? If it is the one I posted there is no such reference in this link, if it is another one please let me know which one. finally I tried giving you an idea of what exactly is the proper way to get the selected value. Hope it helps. Let me now if there is anything else I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

look at this fiddle:
(https://jsfiddle.net/cr1v6cvh/1/)

Get Data

```
<script>

 $("#btnGetData").kendoButton({
    click: function (event){

      var dropdownlist = $("#dataList").data("kendoDropDownList");
      console.log(dropdownlist); 
      console.log(dropdownlist.text()); 
      console.log(dropdownlist.value());    
      console.log(dropdownlist.selectedIndex); 
     }
  })
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ddlData").kendoDropDownList({
      dataTextField: "text",
      dataValueField: "value",
      dataSource: [
        { text: "data 1", value: "1" },
        { text: "data 2", value: "2" },
        { text: "data 3", value: "3" },
        { text: "data 4", value: "4" }
      ]
    });
  });



</script>
```